# Finding top n sub-groups under a main group based on values of a numeric column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data as follows:

```
Category  Brand Sales
Furniture  F1    26
Supplies   S2    12
Tech       T3    17
Furniture  F5    21
Supplies   S7    14
Tech       T2    23
Furniture  F7    24
Supplies   S4    17
Tech       T4    28
```

I want an output using pandas which gives me top 2 Brands for each Category based on Sales as follows:

```
Category  Brand Sales
Furniture F1     26
          F7     24
Supplies  S4     17
          S7     14
Tech      T4     28
          T2     23
```

Please if anyone can help me with this as I'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sort by `Sales` in descending order and then use `groupby` + `head(2)` to get the top 2 values:

```
(df.sort_values('Sales', ascending=False)
   .groupby('Category')
   .head(2)
   .sort_values('Category'))

    Category Brand  Sales
0  Furniture    F1     26
6  Furniture    F7     24
7   Supplies    S4     17
4   Supplies    S7     14
8       Tech    T4     28
5       Tech    T2     23
```

Another option is to use `nlargest` in each group:

```
df.groupby('Category', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(2, 'Sales'))

    Category Brand  Sales
0  Furniture    F1     26
6  Furniture    F7     24
7   Supplies    S4     17
4   Supplies    S7     14
8       Tech    T4     28
5       Tech    T2     23
```

Comment: Yess !! Thank you so much. You're a legend !!

Comment: I think my `nlargest` approach is a bit cleaner because it avoids `apply` :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes great approach to directly use `nlargest`. `apply` is not always bad though when there's no internal vectorization available for the operation.

Comment: Agreed. I don't mind looping if it's for a small number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the largest elements using something like

```
idx = df.groupby('Category')['Sales'].nlargest(2).index
```

Now you can index the original dataframe with the second level of the index, which contains the original row indices:

```
df.loc[idx.get_level_values(1)]
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it is `O(n)` rather than `O(n log n)`, since it uses partitioning instead of sorting, which will matter for large datasets.

Of course you can write it all in one line:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Category')['Sales'].nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)]
```

Comment: Yes. This works too. Thanks !!